# Limit evaluation involving an exponent and a radical

Tags: limits

I have difficulties evaluating the limit of

$$-\frac{e \left( \sqrt{2} \sqrt{y {{e}^{y+1}}+1}-y-1\right) }{y {{e}^{y+1}}+1}$$
near $y \to -1^{+}$.
My algebra system gives $ L = -2 e/3$. I have tried l'Hopital's rule and Taylor expansions but I still get $0/0$ forms. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Taylor worked: let $y=-1+h$ with $h\to0^+.$ Then,
$$ye^{y+1}+1=(-1+h)(1+h+h^2/2+h^3/6)+1+o(h^3)=h^2/2+h^3/3+o(h^3)
$$
hence
$$\frac{\sqrt2\sqrt{ye^{y+1}+1}-y-1}{ye^{y+1}+1}=\frac{h\left(\sqrt{1+2h/3+o(h)}-1\right)}{h^2/2+o(h^2)}=\frac{h\left(h/3+o(h)\right)}{h^2/2+o(h^2)}\to\frac23
$$
and (multiplying by $-e$) your limit is $-2e/3.$

Comment: In the second equation isn't it $o(h^2)$ in the radical?

Comment: No, it is $o(h).$ Because $o(h^3)=h^2o(h)$ and $\sqrt{h^2}=h$ (for $h>0$).